# backbone-rails: edit and destroy not working correctly for a scaffold on page load

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone-routing, backbone-rails

## **I have updated my question please look at the updated part:**

I am using `rails-backbone gem` in `rails 4` and i followed a simple example presented on github's page of the gem. Backbone.js is now working fine but when i press browser back button to move back to see my all list of posts then nothing is displayed. It works fine when i press back link that is generated by scaffold. I will write the steps below:

```
rails new demo34
// Edit your Gemfile and add

gem 'rails-backbone'
// Install the gem and generate scaffolding.

bundle install
rails g backbone:install
rails g scaffold User title:string content:string
rails g backbone:scaffold User title:string content:string
rake db:migrate
```

In my `app/views/users/index.html.erb` with the following contents:

```
<div id="users"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Blog is the app name
    window.router = new Demo34.Routers.UsersRouter({users: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

Backbone.js is now working fine but when i press `browser back button` to move back to see my all list of `posts` then `nothing is displayed`. It works fine when i press `back` link that is generated by `scaffold`.

My users_router.js.coffee is as follows:

```
class Demo34.Routers.UsersRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @users = new Demo34.Collections.UsersCollection()
    @users.reset options.users

  routes:
    "new"      : "newUser"
    "index"    : "index"
     ":id/edit" : "edit"
      ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newUser: ->
    @view = new Demo34.Views.Users.NewView(collection: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new Demo34.Views.Users.IndexView(users: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Demo34.Views.Users.ShowView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Demo34.Views.Users.EditView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)
```

**UPDATE:**

Using the following code I got it working for back button for page change events by backbone and turbolinks. Now my backbone texts don't disappear while pressing back buttons. **But there is a problem with page load event also Let me explain with an example what i mean below my code:**

```
 $(document).on ('page:change', function(){

    Backbone.history.stop();
     Backbone.history.start();
     });
```

I do the following:

1. `localhost:3000` (Welcome aboard, you are riding ruby on rails page appears)
2. `localhost:3000/posts` (backbone triggers its `index.jst.ejs` template)
3. clicking `new post` then route changes to `localhost:3000/posts#/new` (`new.jst.ejs`)
4. clicking `create post` button then route changes to `localhost:3000/posts#/id` (`show.jst.ejs')
5. Now clicking on `browsers back button` route changes to `localhost:3000/posts#/new` (`new.jst.ejs`)
6. clicking the back button again takes me to `localhost:3000/posts` (`index.jst.ejs`)

   Here I can see the new entry has been successfully entered.
7. clicking the back button again takes me to `localhost:3000` via reloading.
8. on clicking `forward button` to go back to  `localhost:3000/posts` (`index.jst.ejs`) 
   i can see my entries still.
9. Now if I destroy my entries and go back to `localhost:3000` and come back we will see that the entries are not destroyed.

Comment: Do you have TurboLinks enabled?

Comment: yes...its by default in rails 4 i guess

Comment: If you're using Backbone to handle your routing and you have a single page app then you don't need (or want) TurboLinks. Try removing TurboLinks.

Comment: is there a way where i can keep both backbone and turbolinks?

Comment: Why would you want both? If Backbone is handling your routing then TurboLinks serves no purpose.

Comment: it is not an single page app..i am using backbone for some part of my application and rest part needs turbolinks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478689/best-way-to-handle-backbone-js-in-rails-4-with-turbolinks i am trying this

Comment: there has to be a way

Comment: well you are right @mu is too short. After removing turbolinks it works fine with back button. thanks for help